# Selecting four random numbers from nine without repeats

Tags: arrays, if-statement, vb6

I wanted to generate 9 random numbers. Then I would get 4 random numbers from that 9, but the four random entries* can't repeat.
There are 28 possible outcomes. The randomizing works fine but I don't understand why I can't get the checkboxes to get checked. I've been trying all day please help

```
    Dim rn As New Random
    Dim n(9) As Integer
    n(1) = rn.Next(1, 2)
    n(2) = rn.Next(1, 3)
    n(3) = 1
    n(4) = rn.Next(1, 3)
    n(5) = 1
    n(6) = rn.Next(1, 4)
    n(7) = rn.Next(1, 7)
    n(8) = rn.Next(1, 4)
    n(9) = rn.Next(1, 3)

    Dim loopcount As Integer = 4
    Dim l(4), ln, lm As Integer
    ln = 1
    lm = 1

    l(1) = rn.Next(1, 9)
    l(2) = rn.Next(1, 9)
    While l(2) = l(1)
        l(2) = rn.Next(1, 9)
    End While
    l(3) = rn.Next(1, 9)
    While l(3) = l(2) Or l(3) = l(1)
        l(3) = rn.Next(1, 9)
    End While
    l(4) = rn.Next(1, 9)
    While l(4) = l(3) Or l(4) = l(2) Or l(4) = l(1)
        l(3) = rn.Next(1, 9)
    End While

    MsgBox(l(1) & l(2) & l(3) & l(4))
    MsgBox(n(1) & n(2) & n(3) & n(4) & n(5) & n(6) & n(7) & n(8) & n(9))

    While loopcount > 0
        If ln = 1 Then lm = l(1)
        If ln = 2 Then lm = l(2)
        If ln = 3 Then lm = l(3)
        If ln = 4 Then lm = l(4)

        If l(ln) = 1 & n(lm) = 1 Then 1.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 1 & n(lm) = 2 Then 2.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 2 & n(lm) = 1 Then 3.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 2 & n(lm) = 2 Then 4.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 2 & n(lm) = 3 Then 5.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 3 & n(lm) = 1 Then 6.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 4 & n(lm) = 1 Then 7.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 4 & n(lm) = 2 Then 8.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 4 & n(lm) = 3 Then 9.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 5 & n(lm) = 1 Then 10.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 6 & n(lm) = 1 Then 11.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 6 & n(lm) = 2 Then 12.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 6 & n(lm) = 3 Then 13.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 6 & n(lm) = 4 Then 14.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 7 & n(lm) = 1 Then 15.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 7 & n(lm) = 2 Then 16.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 7 & n(lm) = 3 Then 17.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 7 & n(lm) = 4 Then 18.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 7 & n(lm) = 5 Then 19.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 7 & n(lm) = 6 Then 20.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 7 & n(lm) = 7 Then 21.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 8 & n(lm) = 1 Then 22.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 8 & n(lm) = 2 Then 23.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 8 & n(lm) = 3 Then 24.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 8 & n(lm) = 4 Then 25.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 9 & n(lm) = 1 Then 26.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 9 & n(lm) = 2 Then 27.CheckState = 1
        If l(ln) = 9 & n(lm) = 3 Then 28.CheckState = 1

        ln = ln + 1
        loopcount = loopcount - 1
    End While

    Call Generate()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to either rename your check boxes or use square brackets:

```vb
[1].CheckState = 1 'for example.
```

Also, you've used `&` which should be `And`...

```
If l(ln) = 1 & n(lm) = 1 Then 1.CheckState = 1
```

...should be...

```
If l(ln) = 1 And n(lm) = 1 Then [1].CheckState = 1
```

Though this could be shortened to...

```
[1].CheckState = 1 And (l(ln) = 1) And (n(lm) = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the check boxes have different names. I just changed them to numbers because they are long and to show they are 28, but I can give the original names in the original code if it helps.

Comment: @Wesite : Yea. I just realized the same. :) Thank you :)

Comment: This solved everything. I was very careless. Thank you very much

Comment: @Jan: No problem at all, Jan.  Just to add to this, you could us the `vbChecked` constant to make your code more readable too, along with the `Value` property of the check box.